# convert lat long to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: core-location, latitude-longitude, cllocation

how do i convert lat long to CLLocationCoordinate2D ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your CLLocation with a lat/long like so

```
- (id)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude;
```

You can then use the coordinate property to get the CLLocationCoordinate2D value.

Comment: hi thanks found, i can convert lat long to clcoordinate2d simpley by CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = { lat, long1 }; thanks